# Error of cell edit while vba loop is running

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have this simple code

```
Sub TestEdit()
    Dim s
    While True
        On Error GoTo StopAction
            Cells(1, 1) = 1
StopAction:
        WaitSeconds (1)
        DoEvents
    Wend
End Sub
```

when i'am edit any cell, macros is stopping with run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error.

Real script every 1 second read data from file and add it to the sheet. And i can't edit any cell.

Is where any way to prevent it&

Comment: No, there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing loc-5:

Activesheet.Cells(1,1).value=1

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping maybe you could use Application.OnTime to run the macro every second without using DoEvents.

PS: I believe the While ... Wend structure is deprecated, better use Do While ... Loop

However, without seeing the real macro it is difficult to give an answer that makes sense.